# how to know, which binder is invoked by a specific android thread

Tags: java, android

i am executing "ps -t" command in shell to get the running process and their related threads. It shows me that whatsapp has initiate different binder threads. How i know which specific binder it is invoking?? here is the output

```
app_66    668   94    216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S com.whatsapp

app_66    669   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S HeapWorker

app_66    670   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S GC

app_66    671   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S Signal Catcher

app_66    672   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S Compiler

app_66    673   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S Binder Thread #

app_66    674   668   216352 50824 ffffffff 00000000 S Binder Thread #
```

Comment: `How i know which specific binder it is invoking?` what do you mean by that?

Comment: as you see its showing Binder thread #....i want to know what type of binder is this...is this binding to some hardware or what??

Comment: what **exactly** do you want to achieve? what is your primary goal?

Comment: actually i want to know the detail of this binder thread, what it is doing...Actually i am developing an application that can detect any access to hardware or drivers like camera, gps. I know whatsapp is communicating with these hardware through binders but how i know a specific thread is communicating with what??

Comment: do you know what is `android.os.Binder` used for? it is not for "communicating with these hardware" but for IPC communication: `the core part of a lightweight remote procedure call mechanism designed for high performance when performing in-process and cross-process calls`

Comment: actually for communicating with camera it has to communicate with media server process through binders which then manages the hardware and its functionality for that process.

Comment: i still dont know what details of binder thread do you want to get? even if you got `android.os.Binder` reference, what do you want to do with that?

Comment: Any application want to access camera will bind to media server to get camera services. I want to capture the request or bind to media server.

Comment: android app bind the system service and invoke its methods through remote method invocation. i want to track which user application is binding to system services...

Comment: hmm so you want to spy other apps? fortunately it is not possible

Comment: No i want to detect any spy application. I am a research student and trying to device a solution for background access to system services without acknowledgment

Comment: i want to know which services are used by which application for how much time etc to detect any spy..

Comment: something like [this](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/bindump.html)?

Comment: thank you so much for the help...yes i need something like this